# Change of basis in tangent space of $C\equiv x^2+y^2=z^2, \, z>0$

Tags: matrices, manifolds, change-of-basis, tangent-spaces

Let $C$ be the smooth manifold defined by $x^2+y^2=z^2$ for $z>0$ and consider the following parametrizations:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
\Phi:&\mathbb R^+\times (0,2\pi)&\longrightarrow &C\\
&(t,\theta)&\longmapsto &\Phi(t,\theta)=(t\cos\theta,t\sin\theta,t)
\end{array}
$$
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
\Psi:&\mathbb R^2&\longrightarrow &C\\
&(u,v)&\longmapsto &\Psi(u,v)=(u,v,\sqrt{u^2+v^2})
\end{array}
$$
It is clear that $\{\Phi_1=\partial \Phi/\partial t, \Phi_2=\partial \Phi/\partial \theta\}$ and $\{\Psi_1=\partial\Psi/\partial u, \Psi_2=\partial \Psi/\partial v\}$ define two basis of the tangent space of $C$ on each point:
$$\Phi_1(t,\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,1)=\Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},1\Big),\quad\Phi_2(t,\theta)=(-t\sin\theta,t\cos\theta,0)=(-y,x,0)$$
$$\Psi_1(u,v)=\Big(1,0,\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\Big),\quad \Psi_2(u,v)=\Big(0,1,\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\Big)$$
These basis must be related by a $2\times 2$ matrix but I am not able to find it. Any help?

Comment: Do you know that this manifold is plainly a (half) cone with vertical axis ? This may help you to realize what you are doing...

Comment: A $2 \times 2$ matrix will not account for the 3D "ambiant features". Working in 2D would need you to linearize around the point of interest $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and work in the tangent plane with equation $xx_0+yy_0=z\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}$. Conclusion : look for an affine transformation $X'=AX+B$ in 3D

Comment: Thanks for the support. 

I don't understand why I have to look for an affine transformation in $\mathbb R^3$. Maybe I need only to compute the induced map $(\Phi^{-1}\circ\Psi)_{\star p}:T_pC\to T_{\Phi^{-1}\circ\Psi(p)}C$?

Comment: Thanks for the support. 

I don't understand why I have to look for an affine transformation in $\mathbb R^3$. Maybe I need only to compute the induced map $(\Phi^{-1}\circ\Psi)_{\star p}:T_pC\to T_{\Phi^{-1}\circ\Psi(p)}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between the two coordinated systems it is the polar change
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}u\\\\v\end{array}\right]\longmapsto
\left[\begin{array}{cc}t\\\\\theta\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\\\\\arctan\left(\dfrac{v}{u}\right)\end{array}\right]$$
Call this change $\lambda$.

Then $\Psi=\Phi\circ\lambda$ serves to communicate both systems.

By the chain's rule
$J\Psi|_p=J\Psi|_{\lambda(p)}\cdot J\lambda|_p$, which explicitly is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\\\0&1\\\\\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}&\dfrac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta&-t\sin\theta\\\\\sin\theta&t\cos\theta\\\\1&0\end{array}\right]\cdot
\left[\begin{array}{cc}\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}&\dfrac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\\\\
\dfrac{-v}{u^2+v^2}&\dfrac{u}{u^2+v^2}\end{array}\right]\qquad (*)$$
You should check how up on the subbings
$$t=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\quad\mbox{and}\quad 
\theta=\arctan\left({\dfrac{v}{u}}\right),$$
or
$$u=t\cos\theta\quad\mbox{and}\quad v=t\sin\theta,$$
the relation $(*)$ is preserved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very useful

Comment: I am glad  to be useful